# `align-items: flex-end` breaks `overflow: auto`

Tags: css, flexbox

For some strange reason, adding `align-items: flex-end` or even `flex-start` breaks the nicely scrolled overflow behavior of the pink flexed item because it's taller than the container height.

[image]

If this is expected behavior, help me retain the scroll even in flex-end alignment.

[Here's demo](http://jsbin.com/josasuhusi/1/edit?html,output).

```css
.slidesWrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

.slide {
  overflow: auto;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div style="width: 200px; position:relative; top: 200px; background: silver;">
  <div class="slidesWrap" style="height:200px">
    <div class="slide">
      <div style="height:300px; width:100%; background: pink;">content</div>
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
      <div style="height:30px; width:100%; background: green;">content</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `align-items` and `align-self` properties are clearly breaking the scroll function.

Fortunately, there is a simple and clean alternative: flex `auto` margins.

```css
flex-row {
  display: flex;
}

.slide {
  overflow: auto;
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;

}

.slide > div {
  margin-top: auto; /* pin items to bottom */

}
```

```html
<div style="width: 200px; background: silver;">
  <flex-row class="slidesWrap" style="height:200px">
    <div class="slide" style="">
      <div style="height:300px; width:100%; background: pink;"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="slide" style="">
      <div style="height:30px; width:100%; background: green;"></div>
    </div>
  </flex-row>
</div>
```

More about flex `auto` margins here:

- [In CSS Flexbox, why are there no "justify-items" and "justify-self" properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32551291/3597276)

Comment: so did you like.. invent flex? :}

Comment: LOL. I just use it a lot at work. I'm waiting for browsers to implement [**CSS Grid Layout**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/), so I can start running with that one, too.

Comment: double the fun xD

Answer (score 5):

another way can be : max-height:100%;

```css
.slidesWrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

.slide {
  overflow: auto;
  flex: 1;
  max-height:100%;
}
```

```html
<div style="width: 200px; position:relative; top: 200px; background: silver;">
  <div class="slidesWrap" style="height:200px">
    <div class="slide">
      <div style="height:300px; width:100%; background: pink;">content</div>
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
      <div style="height:30px; width:100%; background: green;">content</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

or max-height + margin without align-items:

```css
.slidesWrap {
  display: flex;
}

.slide {
  overflow: auto;
  flex: 1;
  max-height:100%;
  margin-top:auto;
}
```

```html
<div style="width: 200px; position:relative; top: 200px; background: silver;">
  <div class="slidesWrap" style="height:200px">
    <div class="slide">
      <div style="height:300px; width:100%; background: pink;">content</div>
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
      <div style="height:30px; width:100%; background: green;">content</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

or use column flow :

```css
.slidesWrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  justify-content:flex-end
}

.slide {
  overflow: auto;
  width:50%;
}
```

```html
   <div style="width: 200px; position:relative; top: 200px; background: silver;">
        <div class="slidesWrap" style="height:200px">
            <div class="slide">
                <div style="height:300px; width:100%; background: pink;">content</div>
            </div>
            <div class="slide">
                <div style="height:30px; width:100%; background: green;
">content</div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Birowsky , lol, nop, sometimes its good to a break and look at something else.  For the fun: You could even reverse the scroll(mouse) and show bottom instead top http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/RpdVQJ

Comment: could you help me achieve the same here? http://jsbin.com/fidojey/2/edit?html,output  It's closer to my actual problem and it doesn't work on Safari.

Comment: I just came up with this solution: http://jsbin.com/fidojey/4/edit?html,output but it kinda defies the purpose of `flex`

Comment: @Birowsky yes it does. problem here is `flex-direction:column` and it is useless since of `.anotherWrap` has a single child. block just does fine. What is the purpose of that funny test ?

Comment: It just represents how my deeply nested components are currently related to each other. But yeah.. flex is kinda letting me down on quite a few cases of mine. Considering how much cross platform/browser testing it requires, I guess I'll just change my strategy to 'enhance with flex' in favor of 'all things flex'.